# Jackson deserialization of class

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to deserialize the example below using Jackson?

```
public class A extends HashMap<String,String> {
   //No other methods here for now
}
```

....

JSON Looks like this:

```
{"something": 
   {
   "entry":
   [
     {"key":"one", "value":"avalue"}, 
     {"key":"two", "value":"bvalue"}
   ]
  }
}
```

...

At this time I'm getting error saying: Unrecognized Property Exception for entry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your json is wrong, but I think I see what you're trying.

No it's not possible.  `HashMap<String,String>` implies your object contains only top level string properties like:

```
{
    "something": "value",
    "somethingelse": "value2",
    "someAdditionalThing": "value3"
}
```

To deserialize that you probably need to have a more strongly typed object.  Jackson is falling over trying to turn:

```
{
    "entry":
        [
            {"key":"one", "value":"avalue"}, 
            {"key":"two", "value":"bvalue"}
        ]
}
```

Into a string.

Comment: someone's already fixed it, but you were missing the opening brace on `"key":"one", "value":"avalue"},`